# error creating bean - JpetStore example

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jvm

Please help me resolve this

I am constantly getting this error 
Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource

Thanks

```
 31 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
140 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1774b9b: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Sep 07 15:12:12 CDT 2010]; root of context hierarchy
343 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext-local.xml]
421 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
921 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1774b9b]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18352d8
1187 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mail.properties]
1187 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
1265 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18352d8: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,sqlMapClient,accountDao,categoryDao,productDao,itemDao,orderDao,sequenceDao,propertyConfigurer,accountValidator,orderValidator,petStore,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor]; root of factory hierarchy
1671 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18352d8: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,sqlMapClient,accountDao,categoryDao,productDao,itemDao,orderDao,sequenceDao,propertyConfigurer,accountValidator,orderValidator,petStore,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor]; root of factory hierarchy
1671 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext-local.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sql-map-config.xml]; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/resultMap'.  Cause: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)Sep 7, 2010 3:12:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext-local.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sql-map-config.xml]; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/resultMap'.  Cause: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create sqlMapClient bean in applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is right at the end:

> Cause: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)

You seem to be running your servlet container under JVM security restrictions, and those restrictions are forbidding Spring/iBatis from doing their work.

You haven't told us anything about your environment, though, so I can't suggest a solution.

Comment: Thank you skaffman, I am using Tomcat 6.0.29 and Eclipse and trying the JPetStore example